# pandas splitting columns with regular expressions (separating dates from strings)

Tags: python, regex, pandas, date, split

I read a text file and converted to a list.
I have a big string list contains dates and a messages, and I want to want to separate the date from the message.

Most of the lines are in the format:

```
DD/MM/YY, HH:MM - NAME: message
```

I separated them into date, name, message columns by using simple `split`s.

The problem is, sometimes when the message is long, it doesn't stay in the message, it just goes down a line. For example:

```
DD/MM/YY, HH:MM - NAME: message
more text
```

(not in the same spot in the list. one after the other).

First, I want to move texts that don't have a date, to belong to the last given date.

Second, separating the date from the message

I want ALL of items in the list, to be in the format of `DD/MM/YY, HH:MM - NAME: message more text`.
I guess I'm missing some regex skills in my arsenal. Would love some help in this one.

EDIT:
My current split:

```
history = pd.DataFrame([line.split(",", 1) for line in content], columns=['date', 'message'])
history = history.fillna({'message':''})
history[['time','message']] = history['message'].str.split(' - ', n=1, expand=True)
history[['name', 'message']] = history['message'].str.split(' ', n=1, expand=True)
```

This is not the best work, considering afterward i merged the time and date column, but it didn't create any problems, so I'll patch things later.

Comment: Could you please provide longer piece of the data and example of your code? (how do you split etc).

Comment: @bluszcz I added my current split. This is not that great, because I merged the date and the time afterwards. But it's not the issue I'm worried about

Comment: is it a row has no date and only text or the text is too long and it is in another line. BTW have you checked the row after reading it in pandas